# Sum lists with different lengths

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sum

What's the best way to sum two or more lists even if they have different lengths?

For example I have:

```
lists = [[1, 2], [0, 3, 4], [5]]
```

and the result should be:

```
result = [6, 5, 4]
```

Comment: `The challenge for the most pythonic way is still open.` - what's so unpythonic about `izip_longest`?

Comment: Nothing, it's just an open question, without a single correct answer. The question was intended to collect multiple ways to accomplish the task in order to learn new methods to solve the problem.

Comment: That is not the kind of question that is suited for stackoverflow. You'll probably get flagged for "not constructive".

Comment: I just wanted to know which is the best way. How can I know which one is the best if I only know one? I only wanted to wait some more hours before accept the answer. I really think it's appropriate to ask, but flag me if you think it's not. I don't want to argue.

Comment: "best" and "pythonic" are not always the same thing. The way you have worded your question is not appropriate. The "best" way is one that uses built-in Python libraries (which are the most efficient). Anything you write yourself to duplicate stuff available in a library will be inefficient.  I think you should accept Ashwini's answer.

Comment: That's correct. I think you hit the point. I was wondering if there was another function in the libraries to automatically deal with not equal length lists without having to resize all the lists. Anyway nobody is replying so I'll accept the answer and I'll edit the question removing unnecessary details. Thanks again for the suggestions Burhan, I'll remember them for the next time!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.izip_longest), and use a `fillvalue` equal to `0`

```
In [6]: [sum(x) for x in itertools.izip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=0)]
Out[6]: [6, 5, 4]
```

for Python < 2.6:

```
In [27]: ml = max(map(len, lists))

In [28]: ml       #length of the longest list in lists
Out[28]: 3

In [29]: [sum(x) for x in zip(*map(lambda x:x+[0]*ml if len(x)<ml else x, lists))]
Out[29]: [6, 5, 4]
```

Comment: (provided the user isn't stuck with Python < 2.6)

Answer (score 2):

```
#You can do the same without using predefined header files.
def sumlists(a,b,c):
    sumlist = []
    while(len(a)!=len(b) or len(a)!=len(c)):
        if len(a)>len(b):
            b.append(0)
        if len(a)>len(c):
            c.append(0)
        elif len(b)>len(a):
            a.append(0)
        if len(b)>len(c):
             c.append(0)
        elif len(c)>len(a):
            a.append(0)
        if len(c)>len(b):
             b.append(0)
    for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c):
         sumlist.append(i+j+k)
    return sumlist
 print(sumlists([1,2],[0,3,4],[5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I came up with is the following:

```
result = [sum(filter(None, i)) for i in map(None, *lists)]
```

It's not so bad, but I have to add NoneTypes and then filter them in order to sum up.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for lists with a thousand and a bit elements. checking with if statements weather to append took ages and ages but this ran pretty fast.i had a function,"longestlist" , that identified and returned the longest list but that's pretty easy to write so using that output...

```
def listfiller(a,b,c,d)
  longest = longestlist(a,b,c,d)
  for i in range(len(longest)-len(a)):
    a.append(0)
  for i in range(len(longest)-len(b)):
    b.append(0)
    print(b)
  for i in range(len(longest)-len(c)):
    c.append(0)
  for i in range(len(longest)-len(d)):
    d.append(0)
  return(a,b,c,d)
```